# Extending group actions to vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, vector-bundles

Let $G$ be a group acting on a manifold $M$. Suppose $V$ is a rank $n$ vector bundle on $M$.

Is there any obstruction to extending the action of $G$ to $V$? In how many ways can the action be extended if obstructions vanish?

Given an $n$-dimensional real linear representation of $G$, when can an action of $G$ on $V$ be realized such that its action on $M$ and on each of the fibers of $V$ are the given ones?

I'd also like to know answers to these questions when (1) $G$ is a topological group acting continuously, or (2) $V$ is a principal $H$-bundle for a group $H$.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean an action by vector bundle automorphisms, or an action compatible with the action of $G$ on $M$? In the former case the fact that $G$ acts on $M$ is irrelevant, in the latter $G$ does not act on the fibers of $V$.

Comment: I understand the question as asking for actions which extend the group action to fibre-wise linear maps. If $G$ is a Lie group, acting on itself by, say, left-translations, then this can only happen, if the bundle is trivial, since fixing a basis over one point, you can move this basis across to get a trivialization.

Answer (score 7):

I'll discuss the case of complex bundles and a finite group $G$.  If $V$ admits a compatible action of $G$ then there is a vector bundle $V_{hG}$ with total space $EV_{hG}=(EG\times EV)/G$ over the Borel construction $M_{hG}=(EG\times M)/G$.  There is a canonical map $p\colon M\to M_{hG}$ with $p^*(V_{hG})\simeq V$, so the Chern classes satisfy $p^*(c_k(V_{hG}))=c_k(V)$.  In particular, this implies that the Chern classes $c_k(V)$ are invariant under the action of $G$, so they appear in $E_2^{0,2k}$ of the spectral sequence
$$ E_2^{pq}=H^p(G;H^q(M)) \Longrightarrow H^{p+q}(M_{hG}) $$
Moreover, they can support no differentials and must survive to $E_\infty$. In the real case you could do similar things with Stiefel-Whitney classes and Pontrjagin classes.

Note here that the symbol $H^p(G;H^q(M))$ refers to group cohomology, which is the same as the singular cohomology of the space $BG$ with a local coefficient system determined by the $G$-module $H^q(M)$.  The same argument works for an infinite topological group $G$ except that we are forced to use cohomology of $BG$ with local coefficients in that case.  If $G$ is connected then $BG$ will be simply connected so the local coefficient system must be constant and we just get a spectral sequence
$$ E_2^{pq}=H^p(BG;H^q(M)) \Longrightarrow H^{p+q}(M_{hG}) $$
with ordinary untwisted coefficients.

Comment: You probably mean $EV_{hG}=(EG\times V)/G$. If not then what is meant by $EV$ ?

Answer (score 3):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Fr{Fr}\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\Diff{Diff}\DeclareMathOperator\Sym{Sym}$Another, more geometric, approach to this question is as follows: let $G$ be a Lie group acting on $M$, and let $P$ be a principal $H$-bundle over $M$. (This addresses your question (2), but it includes (1) if you take $P = \Fr(V)$ to be the frame bundle of the vector bundle $V$.)
Now, if the action of $g \in G$ is supposed to lift to $P$, the least we need is an isomorphism $\psi_g \colon P \to \Phi_g^*P$ of $H$-bundles over $M$. For these to actually provide an action, they must satisfy that $\Phi_g^*\psi_h \circ \psi_g$ agrees with $\psi_{hg}$ under the canonical isomorphism $\Phi_g^*\Phi_h^*P \cong (\Phi_h \circ \Phi_g)^*P \cong \Phi_{hg}^*P$.

This can be rephrased more globally as follows: let $\Aut(P)$ denote the group consisting of all diffeomorphisms $P \to P$ over $M$ (i.e. mapping fibres to fibres) that preserve the $H$-action. That is, these are bundle maps which cover any diffeomorphism $M \to M$. This comes with a projection $p \colon \Aut(P) \to \Diff(M)$. The map $p$ is a group homomorphism, and if we consider only diffeomorphisms isotopic to the identity on $M$, then it is even surjective (you can see this by a cohomology argument, or by endowing $P$ with a connection).
Let $\mathcal{G}(P)$ be the fibre of $p$ over $1_M$ (this is the group of gauge transformations of $P$). We thus have a short exact sequence
$$\mathcal{G}(P) \to \Aut(P) \to \Diff_0(M)\,,$$
where $\Diff_0(M)$ denotes the connected component of $1_M$ in $\Diff(M)$.
This is even a short exact sequence of smooth groups (for instance in the world of diffeological spaces).

Our $G$-action is a smooth group homomorphism $\Phi \colon G \to \Diff(M)$, and I will assume that it factors through $\Diff_0(M)$. (Alternatively, assume that for every $g \in G$ a $\psi_g$ as above exists; otherwise there is no chance of finding a lift of the $G$-action $\Phi$ to $P$ anyway.)
Then, we obtain a pullback sequence
$$\mathcal{G}(P) \to \Sym(P) \to G\,,$$
where $\Sym(P) = \Phi^*\Aut(P)$.

A lifting of the $G$ action on $M$ to one on $P$ is now the same as a splitting of the above short exact sequence of *smooth* groups. The obstructions to the existence of lifts thus are the obstructions to splitting this sequence smoothly (I am not sure how well non-abelian group cohomology for diffeological groups is developed, but I would expect it to describe the obstructions; if $G$ is discrete, ordinary group cohomology should suffice). If you find lifts, then the sequence shows that these lifts are a torsor over $\mathcal{G}(P)$; this controls how many lifts there are in case there are any. You can also find a bit more about this in [Bunk, Müller, and Szabo - Smooth 2-Group Extensions and Symmetries of Bundle Gerbes](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.13395).

Answer (score 1):

Let me point out that if $G$ is disconnected, then the action might not extend. The simplest example I can think of would be a real line bundle over a torus with $w_1$ equal to one of the cohomology generators. Then a ${\mathbb Z}_2$ action that switches the two generators of cohomology will not extend, because the bundle is not preserved. One can do the same with complex line bundles, e.g. on $S^2 \times S^2$.